# Issue deploying a contract successfully with Truffle and ganache

Tags: truffle, ganache, truffle-test

Long story short my contract is not passing the deployment test using truffle, mocha, and chai.

I ran the code individually in the truffle console and it was returning an address just fine but it won't pass the test I wrote. I'm positive I wrote the mocha test well but I can't figure it out.

side note: running `truffle test`  from the truffle console causes node.js to throw an error. However, running `truffle test` from the CLI works fine and just returns `0 passing`.

Here is the code

```
const { expect } = require('chai')
.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
.should()

const Auction = artificats.require('./implementor.sol');

contract('Go',(accounts) => {
    let contract 
    
    describe('deployment',async() =>{
        it('deploys successfully',async ()=>{
            contract = await Go.deployed()
            const address = contract.address
            console.log(address)
            console.log('ran')
            assert.NotEqual(address,'')
        })
    } )
})
```

So I tried it this way because I thought maybe the contract wasn't being created at all.

```
const { expect } = require('chai')
.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
.should()

const Auction = artificats.require('./implementor.sol');

contract('Go',(accounts) => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        this.Go = await Go.new()
    });
    
    describe('deployment',async() =>{
        let contract 
        it('deploys successfully',async ()=>{
            contract = await Go.deployed();
            const address = contract.address;
            assert.NotEqual(address,'');
            return(address);
        });
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least a couple of issues to be addressed:

- You should replace `artificats` by `artifacts`
- You should use the correct variable when creating the new contract instance. In your case, `Auction` instead of `Go`.

In summary:

```
const Auction = artifacts.require('./implementor.sol');

contract('Go',(accounts) => {
    let Go;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        Go = await Auction.new()
    });

    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So @sergi Juanati was correct my spelling was super off. However, that wasn't the reason I wasn't getting anything returned not even an error. The reason is for some reason running

```
truffle test
```

wasn't running the actual test. No matter which directory I was in it was not running the test so I had to specify it myself. I appreciate all the help!.